# Does Convexity play a role in topological equivalence?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

Does convexity of two shapes play a role in them to be topologically equivalent?

For example, a circle and a heart (as asked in another question I posted).

They are homeomorphic, but the circle is convex whereas the heart is not. Does that mean they are not topologically equivalent?

Please excuse my layman's terminology, as I am only starting topology now.

Comment: There are various versions of convexity out there, all of which use some extra structure: Complex structure (holomorphic convexity), algebraic structure (convexity in algebraic geometry), Riemannian metric (geodesic convexity) etc etc. So no, convexity is not topological.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't. When defining a topological space you have two pieces of information:

1. The space as a set.
2. The topology, as a collection of subsets of the space with certain properties.

You can think of the topology as the information which tells you if two points are near one another, or which parts of the space are close. The topology is like a set of instructions telling you how to "glue" the different parts of the space. Nothing else. How would you tell if a set is convex with only a family of its subsets?

For this reason two spaces are topologically equivalent if, and only if, there is a function, with an inverse, both which preserve the "closeness" property of each space. This doesn't depend on the shape of the space, while it depends on other properties, like holes, connectivity, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Convexity is not a topological property, but being homeomorphic to some convex set is.